# What's the difference between Helm list and Kubectl get deployments?

Tags: kubernetes

Can someone explain the difference between what you get in the outputs of a **helm list** and **kubectl get deployments** command  ?
I'm running these commands on a sever and some entries appear whether you do a 'Helm List' **or** a 'Kubectl get deployments' command  and some entries only appear if you run either of the commands. I am pretty new to this obviously.
Any help gratefully received

Answer (score 1):

Helm is some sort of "package manager" for Kubernetes.  `helm list` would give you a list of Helm Charts ("packages") that were applied

`kubectl get deployments` gives a list of Deployment objects. Which may, or may not, be related to Charts applied onto that namespace.